# as3 : Error #1063 MethodInfo-165() Argument Mismatch

Tags: actionscript-3

I encountered an error in Flash CS5.5 ( ActionScript 3 ) :

> ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on
>   MethodInfo-185(). Expected 1, got 0. at MethodInfo-186()

But I have no `MethodInfo-185()` and `MethodInfo-186()` . What's wrong with the Flash ?

Comment: Do you have inline functions declared somewhere around your code?

Comment: No. I searched around but this method cannot be found, even in .as files.

Comment: obviously you won't as it is auto-generated name, Vesper meant the anonymous functions e.g. declared as:
var a:Function = function(){};
or as handler e.g. for event
addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){});

your error looks like this kind of issue as you could easily forget to add event argument:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow Flash CS5.5 / AS3 compiler cannot identify nested functions. The compiler will refer nested functions ( `myInnerFunction` as example below ) as `MethodInfo-123()` ( or something similar ).

```
function myFunction() {
  function myInnerFunction() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means yes, you have there an unnamed function. Make sure you have all event listeners enumerated, and check if you have a listener added like this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,function():void {...});
```

Any event can be in place of an enter frame event I wrote. If so, this is the line with an error. An event listener function should always accept 1 parameter of corresponding Event type. In this case, the correct line should be:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,function(e:Event):void {...});
```

Note the parameter type. If you, for example, listen for a "click" mouse event, it should be of MouseEvent type instead.